# MySQL Update a table from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named history and history detail. The history table provides me a count of gym access by month, so there is duplicate users. I am wanting to update the history detail table to reflect what months users accessed the gym. I have updated the history detail table making the user name unique so there is no duplicates. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve in the history detail table.

History

| Gym Use  | Month |
| Jones   |  April |
| Smith   |  April |
| Jones   |  March |
| Jones   |  Febru |
| Smith   |  Janua |

History Detail

| Gym Use  | Jan | Feb | Mar | April |
| Jones _   |  _   |  X  |  X  |   X   |
| Smith _   |  X  |   _  |  _   |   X   |

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I am wanting to copy the month from the history table and place it in the corresponding month in the history detail table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE history_detail SET Jan='X'
WHERE Gym_User IN (SELECT Gym_User FROM history WHERE Month='Janua');
UPDATE history_detail SET Feb='X'
WHERE Gym_User IN (SELECT Gym_User FROM history WHERE Month='Febru');
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you! You made it look so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a pivot query:

```
SELECT `Gym Use`,
       min(IF( `Month` = 'April', 'X', '_' )) As April,
       min(IF( `Month` = 'March', 'X', '_' )) As March,
       min(IF( `Month` = 'Febru', 'X', '_' )) As Febru,
       min(IF( `Month` = 'Janua', 'X', '_' )) As Janua
FROM history
GROUP BY `Gym Use`
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f71c5/1

and use a result of this query in multitable update:

```
UPDATE `history detail` h, (
   SELECT `Gym Use`,
          min(IF( `Month` = 'April', 'X', '_' )) As April,
          min(IF( `Month` = 'March', 'X', '_' )) As March,
          min(IF( `Month` = 'Febru', 'X', '_' )) As Febru,
       min(IF( `Month` = 'Janua', 'X', '_' )) As Janua
   FROM history
   GROUP BY `Gym Use`
) x
SET h.April = x.April, h.March = x.March, h.Febru = x.Febru, h.Janua = x.Janua
WHERE h.`Gym Use` = x.`Gym Use`
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c153/1

Comment: This solution is a lot prettier than mine.